# How to retrieve data from a polymorphic MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, polymorphic-associations

I have three tables in MySQL: `application`, `questions`, and `questions_answer`.

`application` stores `user_id`; `questions` stores `question_id` and the `type of questions` (i.e Name, NRIC, Name of School); `questions_answer` stores the `answers` referencing to `user_id` and `question_id`.

From what I understand, this type of association is called polymorphic association. Now I am at lost of how to retrieve data from different question_id and make them as column header instead.

I hope that makes sense.

Edit:

To illustrate, here are the respective table:

`application`:

```
user_id         name
-------------------------------
100             Leon Barnacles
101             Richard Kennard
102             Fareeza Salleh
```

`questions`:

```
question_id     question_name
---------------------------------------------   
20              NRIC
21              Have you ever applied to TFM?
22              What's your current GPA?
23              Name of school
```

`questions_answer`:

```
question_id     user_id     answer
------------------------------------------------
20              100         880808-06-8990
20              100         900990-14-0911
23              102         SMK Taman Pandamaran
```

What I hope to retrieve:

```
Name                NRIC                Name of school
------------------------------------------------------------
Leon Barnacles      880808-06-8990      
Richard Kennard     900990-14-0911
Fareeza Salleh                          SMK Taman Pandamaran
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `PIVOT` type function, MYSQL doesn't support PIVOT like SQL Server or Oracle. You can use following script to achieve `pivot` using `max and case` on questions table data

```
select group_concat(concat('max(case when question_id = ''', question_id, ''' then
             answer end) as `', question_name ,'`')) into @sql from tfm_questions;

set @sql = 
concat('select full_name, ', @sql, ' from 
          (
             select a.full_name, q.question_name, an.answer, q.question_id
             from tfm_application a
             inner join tfm_questions_answer an on a.user_id = an.user_id
             inner join tfm_questions q on an.question_id = q.question_id
          ) x
       group by full_name');


select @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/004b8/18)

Comment: I keep getting syntax error on `declare`. Does it need additional syntax to be able to work?

Comment: Still getting the same message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version...`

Comment: @Khairul, can you create [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample tables and data